# Elaboração de uma aplicativo para publicação de eventos

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, android-studio

Estou querendo fazer um aplicativo para eventos ele ta em desenvolvimento mais como eu vou postar as publicações dos eventos no aplicativo tipo vai ter uma evento em tal canto eu quero que esse evento apareça no aplicativo como eu faço isso para o que eu publiquei apareça no aplicativo

Comment: Adicione por favor dar mais detalhes à pergunta, da forma como está não me parece fácil saber o que quer perguntar.

Comment: Onde vai ser feita a publicação dos eventos?

Comment: Vc precisa desenvolver (ou usar) um Back End ou seja, precisa de uma área administrativa com formulários pra todas as áreas que vc quer postar dados, seu aplicativo irá acessar essas infos e apresentar no App. Resumindo, vc posta numa área que ninguém tem acesso e ele aparecerá aonde vc disser pra ele aparecer, seja num aplicativo, num site ou outra mídia.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, a sua dúvida é relacionada a como notificar todos os usuários quando houver a adição de um novo evento no aplicativo, certo? Nesse caso, você deve usar `Push Notifications`, que é um método que permite o envio de informações para um cliente mesmo que ele não a solicite diretamente ou não esteja usando o aplicativo.

Para utilizar este tipo de serviço em aplicações Android, você pode usar o [GCM ( Google Cloud Messaging)](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm). Dá uma olhada lá e quando você tiver dúvidas mais específicas, volte aqui que faremos o possível para ajudar.

Comment: tenho uma duvida, depois que foi feito o aplicativo. como faço para que ele receba a atualização ?

Comment: Como o [Fábio Duarte](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/27385/f%c3%a1bio-duarte) disse, você precisará de um Back End, ou seja, um programa em servidor cujo objetivo é fazer a administração dos dados da sua aplicação. Nesse caso, quando você adicionar uma nova informação no Back End, ele automaticamente enviaria uma notificação para todos os celulares que possuem o aplicativo.